# How do I access files from the webserver in a secured folder using Silverlight

Tags: security, iis, iis-7, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight 4 application that needs to retrieve documents for download. These documents are on a file share accessible by the web server.  How can I do that without exposing the web server to unauthorized request for these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an http handler, I then had the http handler access server resources. I then returned the resource from the handler.

Answer (score 1):

William, there is WebClient class which you can use to access some web resource. Be aware of domain cross policy restriction is Silverlight.